# Google Apps Script: Create new file and get it's URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following to duplicate a template (GoogleDoc) and save it as a PDF.

```
 ....
 const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
 const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
 pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName);
```

What would be the most efficient way to get the URL of the created PDF file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geturl) and store it in a variable.

#### Code:

```
const tempFile = docFile.makeCopy(tempFolder);
const pdfContentBlob = tempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
const url = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfContentBlob).setName(pdfName).getUrl();
```

#### Sample Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [`getUrl`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geturl)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I see now that I was trying to use getUrl() in the incorrect place. Much appreciated.